# Office 2016 installation halts with message "Another installation is in progress"

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2016

I was trying to do a complete purge of Microsoft Office, due to some issues I've been having with Outlook. I uninstalled office, and proceeded to reboot; this was requested as part of the uninstall to finish cleaning up some files. During the reboot, my PC blue screened.

I also did a search in `c:` for "outlook" and deleted pretty much everything I could find, to make sure no settings were left over.

Now when I try to run the installer for Office 2016, it errors out with:

[image: Office 2016 Error]

I get this even in safe mode. I've tried running CClean, but it didn't do anything. I tried the `FixIt` thing from the link in the error, but it didn't find any issues.

What else can I try?

keywords: Office 2016; Error Code: 0-1018 (0);

Comment: Check the Registry for any leftover Office keys and delete them. You might search for the location of both the principle Office directory and its other files in *C:\Program Files\Common Files*. Also, check that there *isn't* another long-running installation in progress, e.g. Windows Update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several hours, I was able to find the answer to this.

[Source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manually-uninstall-Office-2013-or-Office-365-1d1110d5-75a4-4154-969e-4260ff29b232?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

---

### **Manually uninstall Office 2013 or Office 365**

Note: Before you start, you need to know removing Office manually is a long, complex process and might require that you reinstall the operating system if certain steps are done incorrectly.

**Manually remove a Click-to-Run installation of Office**

Before you begin, make sure that you log on to Windows with an administrator account. If you’re not sure if you have an administrator account, see how to determine your user account type in Windows.

- ***Step 1***: Remove the Windows Installer packages

  Find the Office 15 installation folder, typically located in `C:\Program Files\`.

  Right-click the `Microsoft Office 15` folder and select `Delete`.
- ***Step 2**: Remove the Office scheduled tasks*

  Open a Command Prompt window as an administrator.

  At the command prompt, type the following commands and press Enter after each one:

`schtasks.exe /delete /tn "\Microsoft\Office\Office 15 Subscription Heartbeat"`

`schtasks.exe /delete /tn "\Microsoft\Office\Office Automatic Update"`

`schtasks.exe /delete /tn "\Microsoft\Office\Office Subscription Maintenance"`

- ***Step 3**: Use Task Manager to end the Click-to-Run tasks*

  Open Task Manager.

  - Windows 7: Right-click an empty area of the taskbar, and then click Start Task Manager.
  - Windows 8 or 8.1: Point to the upper-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer down, and then click Search. Type Task Manager in the search box, and then click Task Manager in the results.

  Click the Process tab.

  If the following processes are running, right-click each one, and then click End Process in Windows 7 or End Task in Windows 8 or Windows 8.1 after you select each process.

  `Officeclicktorun.exe`

  `appvshnotify.exe`

  `firstrun.exe`

  `setup*.exe`
- ***Step 4**: Delete the Office service*

  Open a Command Prompt window as an administrator, type the following command, and then press Enter:

  `sc delete Clicktorunsvc`
- ***Step 5**: Delete the Office files*

  Press `Windows logo key + R` to open the Run dialog box.

  In the Open box, type `%ProgramFiles%`, and then click `OK`.

  Delete the `"Microsoft Office 15"` folder.

  Open the Run dialog box, type `%ProgramData%\Microsoft`, and then click `OK`.

  Delete the `ClickToRun` folder. If the folder does not exist, go to the next step.

  Open the Run dialog box, type `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\office`, and then click `OK`.

  Delete the `FFPackageLocker` folder.

  Note   If you can't delete a folder or a file that's open or that's being used by another program, restart the computer, and then try again. If you still can't remove the folder, go to the next step.
- ***Step 6**: Delete the Office registry subkeys*

**Important** Follow the steps in this section carefully. Serious problems may occur if you modify the registry incorrectly. Before you start, back up the registry for restoration in case problems occur.

Open Registry Editor.

```
- Windows 7: Click Start, type Run in the Start Search box, and then click Run in the results.

- Windows 8 or 8.1: Point to the upper-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer down, and then click Search. Type regedit in the search box, and then click regedit.exe in the results.
```

Delete the following registry subkeys:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\ClickToRun`

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppVISV`

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Microsoft Office <Edition>15 - en-us`

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office`

Then `Delete` the Office key.

**Note**   In the subkey in the third bullet item, "`Microsoft Office 15 <Edition>- en-us`" represents the actual program name. This name depends on the Office 2013 edition and language version that you installed.

- ***Step 7**: Delete the Start menu shortcuts*

  Open a Command Prompt window as an administrator.

  Type `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`, and then press Enter.

  Delete the `Office 2013` folder.
- ***Step 8**: Uninstall the Microsoft Office Habanero local component and Habanero supplemental local component*

  Open a Command Prompt window as an administrator.

  At the command prompt, type the command that is appropriate for your operating system, and then press Enter:

  - If you're running an x86 version of Office 2013 on an x64 operating system, run the following command:

  `MsiExec.exe /X{50150000-008F-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE}`

  - If you're running an x86 version of Office 2013 on an x86 operating system, run the following command:

  `MsiExec.exe /X{50150000-007E-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}`

  - If you're running an x64 version of Office 2013 on an x64 operating system, run the following command:

  `MsiExec.exe /X{50150000-008C-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE}`