# Can't uninstall Office 2016 Preview, need to install 2015 edition. What do I do?

Tags: installation, microsoft-office, uninstall

When I was trying to install Office 365 (2015) onto my computer, I received a message that I could not install it because I had a newer version of Office, the 2016 Preview. I tried uninstalling it in several ways so that I would be able to install the 2015 edition: 
Operating System: Windows 8.1 64-bit

1. I used Microsoft FixIt to try and uninstall the preview, but the files of 2016 were still there
2. I went to the Control Panel and tried uninstalling the software, but then Office said there was a problem ("Something went wrong"), with the following code: 30034-4
3. I tried deleting all the program files, including from the Recycle Bin, but Office 2016 still showed up in my list of programs.
4. Whenever I tried to clean up all the program files, upon restart, the program still showed up; it also showed up after restart when I used the FixIt tool.

How do I remove the Office 2016 Preview from my computer so I can  install 2015? 
Thank you very much in advance for helping; any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: How about install/repair Office 2016, than try to uninstall it again.

Comment: Try this [Office removal Fixit tool](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9815935) from Microsoft.

Comment: This link might help you!
[Office 2016 installation halts with message “Another installation is in progress"](http://superuser.com/questions/944057/office-2016-installation-halts-with-message-another-installation-is-in-progress)